# How to import compressed file from FTP server to PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ftp, gzip, tar

Is there an elegant way to import a compressed file from a FTP server to a PostgreSQL database? In more detail:

1. The file is sitting on a (credential protected) FTP/SFTP/Webdav server
2. The file is compressed: Multiple csv files inside a tar.gz file (18GB)
3. PostgreSQL database is on AWS (administered through pgadmin)

If anyone has a good idea this would be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Import data on s3,  you can than use Amazon RDS  which has option to import data stored on s3 in postgress table.

Comment: Do the csv files have header rows?

Comment: @jjanes: Yes they have header rows

Comment: @NomanKhan thanks for your input. I am going through the steps to see if I can make this work